# rearrange dataframe multi-level columns by inverting the levels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Given a `pandas.DataFrame` with a column `MultiIndex` as follows

```
A      B     C
X Y Z  X Y Z X Y Z
```

how to rearrange the columns into this format?

```
X      Y     Z
A B C  A B C A B C
```

(I tried `.columns.swaplevel(0,1)`, but that does not yet yield the desired grouping)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df.swaplevel` with `axis=1` (for columns) is what you need.

```
>>> df.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
   X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z
   A  A  A  B  B  B  C  C  C
0  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
```

You can use `sort_index` to sort:

```
>>> df.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
   X        Y        Z      
   A  B  C  A  B  C  A  B  C
0  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
```

Comment: I see, I got confused by how it is displayed (not grouped by X Y Z), but it is actually the right form.

Comment: @clstaudt, to rearrange columns so that all the X, Y, and Z are together, try: `df.sort_index(axis=1)` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html